# Context API vs MongoDB Usecase/Performance?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-native, use-state

I currently have a MERN app that uses Mongodb as the database. I am implementing Context API to learn about global state. I can imagine some simple cases of using Global State, for instance, a number on the dashboard showing the amount of completed actions in the app(You completed four challenges today). But I am having a hard time grasping the use case of this vs querying the database directly(Select Count From Table Actions where actions = completed). Is it much faster than queuring the database? Can someone explain to me some real examples that contextAPI could actually improve. If you could apply it to my app that would be great as well, my app is basically a social media app, where users will be able to complete certain things and share those accomplishments with other users etc.